# Optimizing strucchange with Rcpp

Tags: r, optimization, rcpp

I'm trying to speed up the breakpoints.formula function in the strucchange package ([source](https://github.com/cran/strucchange/blob/master/R/breakpoints.R)). It has a bottleneck in the extend.RSS.table.
Here's my attempt at rewiring the `for(i in my.index)` loop inside it using Rcpp:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix fillMyRSStable(NumericMatrix myRSStable, List & RSStriang, IntegerVector & myIndex, int m, float h) {

  NumericMatrix myRSStableCPY = clone(myRSStable);
  CharacterVector indexI(1), indexj(1);
  int n = myIndex.size();
  CharacterVector nms = rownames(myRSStableCPY);

  for(int myIndexI = 0; myIndexI < n; ++myIndexI) {
    int i = myIndex[myIndexI];

    IntegerVector potIndex =  seq((m - 1)*h, i - h);
    //sapply
    int np = potIndex.size();
    NumericVector breakRSS(np);

    for(int pin = 0; pin < np; ++pin) {
      int j = potIndex[pin];
      NumericVector RSStriangI = as<NumericVector>(RSStriang[j]);

      indexj[0] = j;
      IntegerVector matchedIdxJ = match(indexj, nms);

      breakRSS[pin] = myRSStableCPY(matchedIdxJ[0] - 1, 1) + RSStriangI[i - j - 1];
    }
    // end sapply
    int opt = which_min(breakRSS);

    indexI[0] = i;
    IntegerVector matchedIdxI = match(indexI, nms);

    myRSStableCPY(matchedIdxI[0] - 1, 2) = potIndex[opt];
    myRSStableCPY(matchedIdxI[0] - 1, 3) = breakRSS[opt];
  }
  return myRSStableCPY;
}
```

This code is a bit faster than R but not nearly as fast as I would have thought. Any glaring inefficiencies in the code below that someone can spot? Any general (or specific) advice would be helpful.

**Edit** Code for profiling:

```
library(strucchange)
library(profvis)
library(microbenchmark)
data("Grossarl")
pr <- profvis(microbenchmark(Grossarl.bp <- breakpoints(fraction ~ 1, data = Grossarl, h = 0.1)))
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(pr, "profile.html")
```

Link to my Rcpp version: https://github.com/s-Nick-s/strucchange

Comment: Have you tried to profile the code to see where the bottleneck is within that function?

Comment: @RalfStubner In the R code the exact line of the bottleneck is `break.RSS <- sapply(pot.index, function(j) my.RSS.table[as.character(j), 2] + RSS(j+1,i))`. I am not sure how can I profile my Rcpp function.

Comment: Ok, that would be https://github.com/cran/strucchange/blob/0e5bec6dc510f91ba3fe49dc73a8fe0b01cb2cde/R/breakpoints.R#L94. Can you [edit] your question to include the calls you used for profiling?

Comment: @RalfStubner Of course. I've also added a link to my Rcpp version.

Comment: What sort of speed-up did you expect? For me using your test case the time spend in `extend.RSS.table` goes down from 17s to 3-4s, i.e. your solution is about 5 times faster.

Comment: @RalfStubner That is really strange. On my end time changes from 13.5 to 10 seconds. Maybe it has something to do with my R version? I'm running R 3.4.4 on Windows 10.

Comment: Difficult to tell. I am using R 3.5.2 on Linux (Debian stable). so it might also be the OS or the compiler version.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could write a self-contained example, rather than people trying to figure out where and how to insert the C++ function into your code.  One small, but specific optimization would be to use `std::string` for `IndexI` and J.  As for general advice, a different approach you could try is to rely more heavily on STL vectors and methods, rather than R sugar functions.  You are likely doing some redundant calculation e.g., by first matching indices and the substituting, rather than treating the whole problem in a single for loop.